# Integrating jBPM and Struts2

Tags: struts2, jbpm

I want to integrate jBPM with Struts2. jBPM and Struts2 seems to be pretty simple but when it comes to integration I am having a problem. The problem is that jBPM and Struts2 both are running in different context. How am i suppose to get the request and response object of Struts2 context in jBPM context. Can any one provide me with a good design on that how should I integrate. Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the documentation of jBPM ([Chapter 18 - Integration](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.2/userguide/ch18.html#d0e4330)) about integration with Spring, this way you can use an Struts2 <-> Spring <-> jBpm schema. Also you should check [Activiti](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#springintegration) wich is a great and ligthweight BPM engine which integrates easily with Spring.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nickmancol. I have been through this already. The problem is that this is with Spring where as i need it purely with struts2. Can you give me guidelines for that?

Comment: Well, maybe you can implement your own ObjectFactory (you can check the code from the springobjectfactory o guiceobjectfactory) to integrate the struts 2 context and the jbpm context.

Comment: Any reasons not using Spring?